# Are these JQuery calls the same?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Could someone tell me if this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.html',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        }
    });
```

is the same as this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.html',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + $(data).html());
        }
    });
```

When retrieving this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>blank page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Some content.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I ask because the second jquery ajax call does not alert. Could someone explain why the two versions of the alerts are not the same please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [jQuery Documentation for the $-function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument):

> Simple elements without attributes,
>   e.g., "", are created via
>   document.createElement. All other
>   cases are parsed by assigning the
>   string to the .innerHTML property of a
>   div element. The HTML string cannot
>   contain elements that are invalid
>   within a div, such as html, head,
>   body, or title elements.

You cannot put a full html-page into the $-function, only elements that are valid in a `div`-element.

Comment: I believe the problem is as I stated in my answer, as mentioned in your link "A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, *not* XML."

Comment: Doesn't really matter, since neither a complete HTML nor XHTML/XML page can be put into the $-function. Just HTML-elements allowed under div and there HTML/XML doesn't matter.

Comment: Reading further through the Ajax section of the JQuery online docs (.load - http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) I see; "In jQuery 1.2 you can now specify a jQuery selector in the URL. Doing so will filter the incoming HTML document, only injecting the elements that match the selector." Does this imply that load() does not use the $() function? If so, how can it work?

Answer (score 1):

Because the doctype is XHTML, the first example is returning XML.  So, when you alert the XML it is correct.  In the second example, jQuery must think it's XML, which can't be accessed with .html().

To get the second example to work try the option

```
dataType: "html"
```

Comment: Adding your line to the second example didn't work for me, for the reasons stated in the answer above, by stefanw, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The second example isn't calling `alert` because an error is occurring inside of the `success` callback.  Switch firebug on and you should see that an error is happening (though the line that firebug tells you it's occurring on won't be accurate).  If for some reason firebug doesn't show you an error is happening, it's because jQuery is gracefully handling exceptions from the functions assigned to `success`.  You could wrap your `alert` with a try/catch block and see for yourself.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.html',
        success: function(data) {
            try {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + $(data).html());
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Error happened: " + e.message);
            }
        }
    });
```

That error is happening because the data being returned isn't an actual HTML element.